# How to use trim() for persian characters

Tags: php, wordpress

Any help would be awesome thanks.
How to use this code for Persian characters?

```
function ae_filter_badword($content){
    // filter badwords
    $filter_word     = ae_get_option('filter_keywords');
    $filter_keywords = explode(',', $filter_word);

    if(!empty($filter_keywords)){
        foreach ($filter_keywords as $word) {
            if($word){
                $partern = '/\b' . trim($word) . '\b/i';
                $content = preg_replace($partern, " ***", $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual string you have and what the behavior you currently get is?

Comment: function ae_filter_badword($content){
    // filter badwords
    $filter_word     = ae_get_option('filter_keywords');
    $filter_keywords = explode(',', $filter_word);

    if(!empty($filter_keywords)){
        foreach ($filter_keywords as $word) {
            if($word){
                $partern = '/\b' . trim($word) . '\b/i';
                $content = preg_replace($partern, " ***", $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

Comment: The string above is the actual

Comment: `$content` is undefined above..

Comment: $content is actually the words they want to filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,Just use the following code

```
        $partern = '/\b' . trim($word) . '\b/u';
```

u means utf-8